# Logging in a user to a Web API application

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api, simplemembership, antiforgerytoken

I have coded a C# Web API application and some of the calls require the user to be logged in.

Here is my current code to log the user in:

```
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public bool TestLogon(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
    return WebSecurity.Login(userName, password, persistCookie: rememberMe);
}
```

My question is this:
How secure is the above call? Is the above code secure enough for a commercial application, and if not, how can the code be improved? Do I need to implement any sort of AntiForgeryToken?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For WebAPI apps I would recommend you looking at the new ASP.NET Identity system which provides token based authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see my answers below.

**1. How secure is the above call**

Because, by default, the credentials are not encrypted, so if there isn't any encryption in place like SSL to protect communication, the data will not be secure. More details from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/forms-authentication)

**2. Is the above code secure enough for a commercial application, and if not, how can the code be improved?**

Like the other has suggested, you'de better to use Token-Based security, and enable SSL communication. This [link](http://vimeo.com/43603474) is really useful

**3. Do I need to implement any sort of AntiForgeryToken?**

Yes, you will have to prevent cross site request forgery [attacks](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks).

Hope this help.